# Wocoommerce. Удалить предложение из сообщения на почте

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

При создании заказа клиенту попадает письмо, мне нужно удалить строку. Пересмотрел множество файлов. Ни один не дал результата. Нужно либо изменить этот текст на собственный, либо удалить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шёл по файлу `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/plain/customer-invoice.php` И закомментил строку `echo sprintf( esc_html__( 'Here are the details of your order placed on %s:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) ) . "\n\n";`  Но всё равно оно приходит.

Comment: Ну как минимум на скрине у вас не plain письмо

Comment: Да, там письмо из другого файла. В том файле нет этого предложения. Оно есть в plain/customer-invoice.php . В любом случае, я редактировал и "правильный" шаблон и этот - толку нет

Comment: Ну, как вариант, очистить поле "Инструкции" в настройках вашего способа платежа. Это поле показывается на странице "Спасибо" и в email-уведомлениях.